# copy char* to char*

Tags: c++, char

Here is part of my code:

```
extern "C" REGISTRATION_API int extreme(char* lKey)
{
string s1; 
char *p=NULL;
try
{
    ifstream myfile ("extreme.txt");
    int i=0;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
    while (getline(myfile,s1))
       {
        switch (i)
         {
        case 1:
         strcpy(p,s1.c_str());
         lKey=p;
        break;
             //continue here
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now when I call this function from external application, I get this error:

> AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The problem is due to this:

```
lKey=p;
```

How can I assign the `lKey` to `p`?

Comment: Where have you allocated memory to the pointer p?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pre-allocate the memory which you pass to `strcpy`. I.e. a `p = new char[s1.length()+1];` will do it (+1 for the terminating 0 character). However, it's not a good idea to mix up `std::string` and C string routines for no good reason. Better stick with `std::string`, it will save you a LOTS of trouble.

Also `lKey=p` won't work either -- it just copies the local address of `p` into the local variable `lKey`. The caller won't even see a difference.

Comment: What if i want to perform some modifications on p and then assign it to lkey?
let's say:
i call methodone(p);
and i then want to assign the result to lkey, how do i do that?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am facing a similar problem and I found your answer useful. I have one small question : could you elaborate on your second paragraph please? What would be needed instead of lKey=p so that the caller will correctly receive the new value in lkey? Cheers

Comment: @ibiza: lKey needs to be a caller-allocated buffer, then you can `strcpy` to it. Take care of not running over the end of the buffer, though. Alternatively, use a `char**` instead and have the function `malloc` a buffer that is large enough to hold the string.

Answer (score 10):

Actually the problem is `strcpy(p,s1.c_str());` since `p` is never set to anything but NULL.

Comment: @Zee99 strcpy just copies the data. p is a pointer to memory that is not allocated. Therefore when you copy you are just copying to memory location 0, which is illegal.

Answer (score 9):

Remember that a `char*` is just an address of a memory location.  You need to have memory allocated at the address.

In your code you don't have memory allocated to use and you didn't set p to point to that memory address.

`strcpy` does not allocate a buffer, it just takes a memory address to copy the data to.

If you are passing a buffer into the function then you probably want simply this (and remove p)

```
strcpy(lKey, s1.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Eliminate p (it is doing nothing here), and copy the data from s1 directly to lkey
2. Not to beat on you, but the indentation scheme is a travesty, please cop a good style from somewhere ( google 1tbs )