# How to copy contents of the const char* type variable?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I know the difference between:

```
char *a = "string";
char p[] = "string";
```

from `*a`, it acts as the following...

```
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
  a: |  *======> | s | t | r | i | n | g |\0 |    
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If I want to create another variable say

```
char *b;
```

and I hope it copies all contents in pointer a points to instead of pointing to the a's content.

```
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+      
  a: |  *======> | s | t | r | i | n | g |\0 |    
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
  b: |  *======> | s | t | r | i | n | g |\0 |    
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

How to do this ?

Comment: do you want to do this at runtime or compile-time?

Comment: @MarcoA. at runtime. thanks

Comment: awesome art +1 for that makes it very clear.

Comment: You need to allocate memory large enough to hold the string, and make `b` point to that memory. Then you copy the string. How to allocate depends on the language, but once allocated the same function to copy a string can be used (please do some searching). Though, in C++ you should try to avoid C-style strings and pointers as much as possible, and use e.g. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY if you do that@ `b = strdup(a); /*stuff here*/ delete[] a;`  (It is `delete[]` right?)  I'd prefer to allocate on the stack like in the accepted answer personally.

Comment: @Baldrickk `free(b);`, `a` is string literal.

Comment: ah yes, I meant `b` (typo).  and it is `free` because it is a `C` function, right? This is one of those functions I've not actually used myself because things like `std::string` exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy char\* to char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256454/copy-char-to-char)

Comment: Why did cool ASCII art made everyone forgot to look around to find tons of answers to this, and similar questions on SO? :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, you can do

```
const size_t n = strlen(a);   // excludes null terminator
char *b = new char[n + 1]{};  // {} zero initializes array
std::copy_n(a, n, b);
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fefa0c4ca482f9c6)

However I recommend using `std::string` over C-style string since it is

- deals with `\0`-embedded strings correctly
- safe
- easy to use

Comment: Lacks null terminator

Comment: @MarcoA. No it doesn't, since I've initialized it all to 0.

Comment: @MarcoA. I think the confusion is because I earlier put it as `(0)` which only works for a scalar (my bad), for an array `{0}` is correct; even better is to use `{}`. Fixed now.

Comment: Use a variable for the result of strlen(), unless you can expect the strings to be extremely short.

Comment: May I know what's the advantage of using a variable to hold `strlen()`'s result when the strings are long?

Comment: @legends2k So you don't run an O(n) algorithm twice without need? But this will probably be optimized away anyway.

Answer (score 7):

In C, you can allocate a new buffer b, and then copy your string there with standard library functions like this:

```
b = malloc((strlen(a) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(b,a);
```

Note the `+1` in the `malloc` to make room for the terminating `'\0'`. The `sizeof(char)` is redundant, but I use it for consistency.

In C++, you should use the safer and more elegant `std::string`:

```
std::string b {a};
```

Comment: Doesn't this end in the following error: `invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'` because of `malloc` return type?

Comment: @JaviMarzán It would in C++, but not in C. Some even consider casting the return of `malloc` an antipattern in C, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc. (And in C++, you should generally not be using `malloc` to begin with.)

Answer (score 4):

`a`'s content, as you posted, points to a read-only memory location set up by the compiler. If you want to have another one at compile-time with distinct values you'll have to define one yourself:

```
char *a = "string";
char *b = "string"; // Nb. This might point to the same location as a
```

Notice that according to §2.14.5, whether these two pointers will point or not to the same memory location is **implementation defined**

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation deﬁned.

Otherwise go for a heap-stored location like:

```
size_t len = strlen(a); // Doesn't include null-terminator character
char *b = new char[len+1];
memcpy(b, a, len); // Assumes plain ASCII string
b[len] = '\0';
```

I would go for `std::string`s anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non-standard (but available on many implementations) `strdup` function from `<string.h>`:

```
char *b;
strdup(b, a);
...
free(b);
```

or you can reserve space with `malloc` and then `strcpy`:

```
char *b;
b = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
strcpy(b, a);
...
free(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `a` is what you have labelled as `*` in your diagram.  `a` is your little box, and the contents of `a` are what is in the box!

The "string" is NOT the contents of `a`. It's somewhere else in memory, and `a` contains the address of that string.

Copying the contents of `a` to `b` would end up doing this:

```
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+      
a: |  *======> | s | t | r | i | n | g |\0 |    
   +-----+  /  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
b: |  *====/
   +-----+
```

To achieve what you have drawn in your second diagram, you need to take a copy of all the data which `a` is pointing to. This is not straightforward because how do you decide when to stop copying? There's no general way, but if you have predetermined that you just want to copy a string, then you can use a function which copies a string.

The common but non-standard `strdup` function will allocate new space and copy a string. Otherwise, you can allocate space (in any of the usual ways of allocating space in C) and then copy the string over to the allocated space.

Comment: don't forget to `free` the strduped string (b) if you do it that way.